# How do I store rule-related data in RDF?

Tags: sparql, rdf, rules

I have some data on students' test scores as follows:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/#> .
:Bob a :Student;
     :tookTest :Test0,:Test1,:Test2 ,:Test3 .
:Test0 :score 90 .
:Test1 :score 81 .
:Test2 :score 62 .
:Test3 :score 32 .
```

The rules for grading based on scores are as follows:

```
  [90-100]  --> A
  [75-90)   --> B
  [60-75)   --> C
  [0-60)    --> D
```

So I used the following SPARQL query to get the grade of the student's Test:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/#>
select ?student ?test ?grade
    WHERE {  
      ?student :tookTest ?test .
      ?test :score ?score .
      BIND ( IF ( ?score >= 90 , "A", IF ( ?score>=75, "B", IF ( ?score>=60, "C", "D" ) ) ) AS ?grade )
      }
```

And I got the right result as such:

```
student,                  test,                       grade
http://example.org/#Bob,  http://example.org/#Test3,  D
http://example.org/#Bob,  http://example.org/#Test2,  C
http://example.org/#Bob,  http://example.org/#Test1,  B
http://example.org/#Bob,  http://example.org/#Test0,  A
```

Now my question is how to store this rule data in RDF (along with the score) rather than in SPARQL,  so that the rule data can be defined and modified by the user, The server side reads the rule data to generate the appropriate SPARQL query.
My initial thoughts are as follows:

```
 :range1 a :range ；
         :grade "A" ;
         :lowerLimit 90 ;
         :upperLimit 100.
:range2 a :range ；
         :grade "B" ;
         :lowerLimit 75 ;
         :upperLimit 89 .
:range3 a :range ；
         :grade "C" ;
         :lowerLimit 60 ;
         :upperLimit 74 .
:range4 a :range ；
         :grade "D" ;
         :lowerLimit 0 ;
         :upperLimit 59 .
:rule1 :hasRange :range1,:range2, :range3, :range4 .
```

But now how do I make the SPARQL work? And how to consider inclusive and exclusive of boundary values?

Comment: what means "how to make the SPARQL work"? I mean, you have to create the SPARQL query based on your RDF encoded rule or not? Where is the problem? In that case some client code has to generate your SPARQL query

Comment: But, obviously here you could also simply make use a simple filter: `prefix : <http://example.org/#>
select ?student ?test ?grade
    WHERE {  
      ?student :tookTest ?test .
      ?test :score ?score .
      ?range a :range ;
       :lowerLimit ?ll ;
       :upperLimit ?ul ;
       :grade ?grade
 filter(?ll <= ?score && ?ul >= ?score)
      }`

Comment: Thank you Sir. The SPARQL that you gave do work well.  Now a question is how should I express the inclusion and exclusion of boundary limits.  For example, minInclusive, minExclusive, which determines the use of filter(?lowLimit <= ?score) or filter(?lowLimit < ?Score)  in SPARQL, I don't know how to handle it any simpler.

Comment: you can either work with 4 properties then or a bnode like `:lowerLimit [:inclusive false ; :value 50] .` and use this information when building the `FILTER`